# Webstorm 10 IDE: possible to see HTML hierarchy as in Chrome 'inspect element'?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webstorm

Is there a way to display the current hierarchy of an element in an HTML within the WebStorm 10 ID, such as is shown in Chrome 'inspect element'?  Thus if you were in an `<A>` inside a `<DIV>` inside a `<DIV>` you would see a line like

```
<DIV> <DIV> <A>
```

inside the IDE so you could navigate up from that point to an enclosing element? (I know you can successively expand the selection outwards but I'm looking for something that both shows you where you *can* click and then be able to do more quickly).  I've looked through the docs but didn't find.

Comment: In what context: editing a html file .. or document structure during js debug?

Comment: Editing an HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance`

- WebStorm 10 / PhpStorm 9 (any build on branch 142.xxx and older) -- `Show HTML Breadcrumbs` (there is also separate setting for XML)
- WebStorm 11 / PhpStorm 9.5 (branch 143.xxx) -- `Show Breadcrumbs`

Regardless of the IDE version -- just use the search box in the Settings/Preferences screen (top left corner) and look for "breadcrumbs".